# How do you pause a thread?

Tags: c++, powerpc

Hello i'm trying to pause a thread, but for some reason it keeps crashing the game.
here is what i got

```
void Test(){
    SuspendThread((PVOID)0x83593C24);//0x83593C24 The offset from the game
    Scr_AddInt(1);
    ResumeThread((PVOID)0x83593C24);
}
```

Basically i'm trying to pause than call Add Int than resume it

Comment: A thread **is not** some memory address. Look for thread id and process id.

Comment: i fount the threadid which is 0x8354F7A8 but i don't see the processid http://gyazo.com/13a976b7993ce574ff9489d82110f1cc

Comment: That looks much too big for a thread-id...

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information, like what your platform is (PowerPC?); what library provides `SuspendThread` and `ResumeThread`; and what compiler/threading libraries you're using; and what that crazy assembler is.

Comment: im using VS2012 to compile my code. the pic i provided is IDA Pro displaying PowerPC code. and the libraries SuspendThread and ResumeThread are in winbase.h

Comment: 'In memory' has nothing to do with this question. All threads are in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the thread handle that was returned when you created the thread.  See documentation for [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx); [`SuspendThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345(v=vs.85).aspx); and [`ResumeThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685086(v=vs.85).aspx).

In particular, from the documentation for `CreateThread`:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the new thread.  If the function fails, the return value is NULL.

Example:

```
HANDLE thread_handle = CreateThread(/*args*/);  // hold on to this value (and check for failure)
if (thread_handle == NULL)
{
    // handle creation error
} 

DWORD suspend_retval = SuspendThread(thread_handle); 
if (suspend_retval == static_cast<DWORD>(-1))
{ 
    // handle suspend error
}

Scr_AddInt(1);  // original work  

DWORD resume_retval = ResumeThread(thread_handle);
if (resume_retval == static_cast<DWORD>(-1))
{ 
    // handle resume error
}
```

It may be worthwhile to create a wrapper class that encapsulates thread creation, suspension, resumption, and termination.  This class can perform all error checking internally, and throw an exception when appropriate.